# How does a method work as callback in app.use()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Normally, a function is passed as callback in `app.use()`, like so:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('Time:', Date.now());
  next();
});
```

In the case of [node-expose-sspi](https://github.com/jlguenego/node-expose-sspi) however a method is passed:

```
const express = require('express');
const { sso } = require('node-expose-sspi');

const app = express();
app.use(sso.auth()); //stores something in req.sso

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.json({
    sso: req.sso,
  });
});
```

Why is the method passed with `()`? If it uses `()` why is it no called immediately (without arguments)?
Also, how can I wrap a method in a callback function, e.g.

```
app.use(myCallback);

function myCallback(req, res, next) {
  sso.auth(); //req.sso is undefined
}
```

Comment: _"why is it no called immediately (without arguments)"_ - it is called immediately and whatever that function call returns, is used as a callback function

Comment: I'd imagine, `sso.auth()` **returns** a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app.use(sso.auth());
```

calls `sso.auth()` and `app.use()`s its return value.

You can find [over here in the `node-expose-sspi` source](https://github.com/jlguenego/node-expose-sspi/blob/aa53a41f6fbbf58e38cdd8d1643203c093274bcb/src/sso/auth.ts#L70) that `.auth()` indeed returns a new middleware function.

As for the second question

> Also, how can I wrap a method in a callback function

you shouldn't do that – Express will call your `use`d middlewares in order; a subsequent callback will have access to whatever a previous middleware has injected into the request.

If you for some reason *really* need to do that,

```
const ssoAuth = sso.auth();

function myCallback(req, res, next) {
  ssoAuth(req, res, () => {
    // whatever would regularly be in `myCallback`
    next();
  });
}
``
```